# member reference type is a pointer; did you mean to use '->'?

Tags: c++

```
GpuContext* ctx

struct GpuContext
{
/*Input vars*/
size_t deviceIdx;
size_t rawIntensity;
size_t workSize;
int stridedIndex;
int memChunk;
bool isNVIDIA = false;
int compMode;

/*Output vars*/
cl_device_id DeviceID;
cl_command_queue CommandQueues;
cl_mem InputBuffer;
cl_mem OutputBuffer;
cl_mem ExtraBuffers[6];
cl_program Program[2];
cl_kernel Kernels[2][8];
size_t freeMem;
int computeUnits;
std::string name;

uint32_t Nonce;

};

ctx->Program[ii].getBuildInfo((cl_int*)1);
```

I'm trying to run this last line of code.  I provided the relevant code for the rest of the function.  The ii is because the code I'm running is inside a loop.  getBuildInfo is a function call from the cl_program class located here:

https://github.khronos.org/OpenCL-CLHPP/classcl_1_1_program.html

I understand I'm doing something incorrectly.  What I'm trying to do is call the function getBuildInfo on the Program[ii] cl_program object.  The compiler is telling me

```
member reference type 'cl_program' (aka '_cl_program *') is a pointer; did
  you mean to use '->'?
                    ctx->Program[ii].getBuildInfo((cl_int*)1);
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
                                    ->
```

But Program[ii] (cl_program) is not a pointer as you can see from the struct GpuContext.  Is `ctx->Program[ii]->getBuildInfo((cl_int*)1);` correct?

Comment: The link you provided doesn't show the definition of `cl_program`.

Comment: Well, the compiler says it all : `cl_program` seems to be a type alias for `_cl_program*`. This is why you need to use the operator `->`

Comment: You could have removed almost all of the members of `GpuContext` and still shown the problem. Don’t make people wade the irrelevant details to help you out.

Answer (score 2):

`cl_program` is simply a [typedef](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-Headers/blob/320d7189b3e0e7b6a8fc5c10334c79ef364b5ef6/CL/cl.h#L51) for `_cl_program*` where `_cl_program` is a struct. As a result, `Program[ii]` is, in fact, a pointer, and the error message is well-justified.

Comment: Oh ok.  So the arrow operator would be correct then?

Comment: @thecodingmate That's correct; the arrow operator should be used here.